# Regular expression for parsing string in key value pair in java

Tags: java

I have this string:

```
"{ '_id' : ObjectId('4e85ba250364e5a1857ba2e4'), 
   'message' : '<user=animesh@strumsoft.com>, <action=create-flock>, 
      params=[<title=[smile.animesh@gmail.com, ram@strumsoft.com], 
      attendees=immediate, flockType=immediate, duration=30]>' }";
```

I tried following regex on it:

```
private static String REGEXFinal = "<(.*?)>";

private static String REGEX2Final = "<(.*)>";
```

after applying above two regex final out come is

```
user=a@a.com
action=create-flock
title=[a@a.com, b@b.com], attendees=immediate, flockType=immediate, duration=30]
```

but I want O/P in key / value format like

```
user  a@a.com 
action create-flock
title  [a@a.com, b@b.com], attendees=immediate, flockType=immediate, duration=30]
```

how to do this?

Comment: Do you control the string? If so, you can convert the whole string to json instead and use a json parser.

Answer (score 0):

if you got this String

```
user=a@a.com
action=create-flock
title=[a@a.com, b@b.com], attendees=immediate, flockType=immediate, duration=30]
```

Then why not try to do this..

```
String str="user=a@a.com action=create-flock title=[a@a.com, b@b.com], attendees=immediate, flockType=immediate, duration=30]";
str = str.replaceAll("=", " ");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: They want to keep some of the '=' characters such as `attendees=immediate`.  They just want to replace the first one per line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for each line:

```
line.replaceFirst("=", " ");
```